# Add if in Yii bootstrap tbgridview

Tags: php, yii

I've got this

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
'dataProvider'=>$data,
'template'=>"{items}",
'columns'=>array(
    array('name'=>'name', 'header'=>'Name' ,'type'=>'raw', 'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->url),array("view","id"=>$data->id))',),
    array('name'=>'status', 'header'=>'Status', 'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'status'),),
),
```

In status, there are two status: On and Off. I want to add class "green" if the status is on and class "red" if the status is off.

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention, where you want to add that class. If you want to add it to each row, you can use the [`rowCssClassExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#rowCssClassExpression-detail) property of the GridView:

```
// ...
'template'=>"{items}",
'rowCssClassExpression' => '$data->status ? "green" : "red"',
// ...
```

If you only want to add it to a specific column, you can use the [`cssClassExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn#cssClassExpression-detail) of a column:

```
array(
    'name'=>'status',
    'header'=>'Status',
    'htmlOptions' => array('class'=>'status'),
    'cssClassExpression' => '$data->status ? "green" : "red"',
),
```

Comment: I'm using this 'cssClassExpression' => '$data->status=="On" ? "green" : "red"'. Great help!!!